# Is there a Bash wrapper (program/script) that enables a more succinct input when I want multiple outputs in one Bash call

Tags: bash, input, printf, output, echo

I'm currently creating monstrosities like the following:

```
ll /home && echo -e "==============\n" && getent passwd && echo -e "==============\n" && ll /opt/tomcat/ && echo -e "==============\n" && ll /etc/sudoers.d/
```

Is there perhaps some program that handles this in a nicer way?
Something like this (the hypothetical name of the program would be `multiprint` in my example):

```
multiprint --delim-escapechars true --delim "============\n" '{ll /home},{getent passwd},...'
```

alternatively:

```
multiprint -de "============\n" '{ll /home},{getent passwd},...'
```

Comment: I think the biggest improvment that code can benefit is from stopping to write these as one-liners. Then maybe a variable or function for the delimiters, but I'm not sure it's worth having a display function that relegates what's important there, the data-producing functions you call, to the state of attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function like the following would give you that ability :

```
function intersect() {
    delim=$1
    shift
    for f; do cat "$f"; echo "$delim"; done
}
```

You could call it as follows to implement your specific use-case :

```
intersect '==============' <(ll /home) <(getent passwd) <(ll /opt/tomcat/) <(ll /etc/sudoers.d/)
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/tCkzmA).

Comment: `for f; do cat "$f"; echo "$delim"; done` would also suffice.

Comment: @chepner thanks, I thought about using `for` but wasn't sure how to handle the parameters. I'll update my answer to your much simpler syntax.

Comment: I might even consider letting `printf`'s implicit loop handle this: `printf '%s\n=======\n' "$(ll ...)" "$(getent...)" ...`.

Comment: @chepner true, but then that's a whole different answer. Worth posting as your own maybe? :)

Comment: Done, although on second thought it's probably a worse alternative to an explicit loop.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` will repeat its format until its arguments are exhausted. You could write something like

```
printf '%s\n================\n' "$(ll /home)" "$(getent passed)" "$(ll /opt/tomcat)" "$(ll /etc/sudoers.d)"
```

although this is a little memory-intensive, since it buffers all the output in memory until all the commands have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Aaron's answer I ended up creating this `multiprint.sh` Bash shell script, and for what it's worth posting it here:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Print output of multiple commands, delimited by a specified string

function multiprint() {
    if [[ -z "$*" ]]; then
        __multiprint_usage
        return 0
    elif [[ "$1" == "--help" ]]; then
        __multiprint_usage
        return 0
    else
        delim=$1
        shift
        for f; do cat "$f"; echo -e "$delim"; done
    fi
}

function __multiprint_usage() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "  multiprint '<delimiter>' <(cmd1) <(cmd2) ..."
    # example: multiprint '\n\n\n' <(ll /home/) <(ll /var/) ..."
}
```